# Does "Inchoative Construction" mean constructions with intransitive inchoative verbs?

Tags: syntax, english, verbs

The following is the sentence I extracted from a book, *Binding Theory*, written by Daniel Burning.

> The fact that a language like English, which lacks a simple reflexive, has extremely few reflexive verbs, and never uses a reflexive in inchoative constructions may well be related to the emphatic heritage of the reflexive form.

Inchoative verb, according to Wikipedia, sometimes called an "inceptive" verb, shows a process of beginning or becoming.

Then the following sentence just popped into my mind:

> How did I get myself into the mess?

Is this sentence a causative construction? Does inchoative construction mean sentences with intransitive inchoative verbs?

Comment: inchoative means "starting with [action]". Some languages have prefixes or other (syntactic) constructions to express this semantics grammatically. I suppose your terms refers to those? Like the prefix (nonproductive) ont- in Dutch "ontbijten" (to eat breakfast), which etymologically is "ont- (start with, prefix) + bijten (bite, hence eat). Also present in "ontwaren (beginning to see)", "ontvangen(receive, etym. begining to catch)" and "antwoord" (answer).

Comment: For really basic questions, please consider starting with [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inchoative_aspect) or some other linguistic reference. Then you can ask a more specific question here. In this case it's not really clear what you're asking about (inchoative aspects? inchoative verbs?), and it's not clear what you don't understand.

Comment: Right. Thank you for your comment!  The question has been rewritten~

Comment: Thanks, that is much better. But please add a citation for the quote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No one can tell you what *construction* means without some context. It's a very common word in syntax and generally refers to sentence constituents that may be more than one word. That's not very helpful.

However, *inchoative* (pronounced *in KOE a tiv*) has a very specific meaning -- Change of State. Which means beginnings, endings, and changes of all sorts; a pretty large semantic space, edging onto just about everything.

***Inchoative*** and ***Causative*** are terms that are often used together; causative verbs like *kill* mean to cause some change to happen, and the change is an inchoative like *die*, which means 'become dead', while causative *kill* means 'cause to become dead'. *Dead, die, kill* are one triplet like that; *white, whiten, whiten* is another -- verb often the transitive causative has the same form as the intransitive inchoative.

Any verb that refers to a change of state is inchoative; frequently they're metaphors of motion verbs, like *come* and *go*. We use *come to be* and its contraction *become* as generalized inchoative markers -- *He was tired* ~ *He became tired*. In turn, *come* and *go* have their own causative relation with *bring* and *take*, respectively. *Bring* means 'cause to come' (*Fred brought Alice/whisky/brownies/a gun to the party*), and *take* means 'cause to go'.

The best example of inchoation (*in ko A shun*) in English is the verb *get*, which is the causative **and** the inchoative form of *be*:

- *He is tired* (stative) ~ *He got tired* (inchoative) ~ *They got him tired* (causative)

as well as the causative **and** the inchoative form of *have*:

- *He has a new car* ~ *He got a new car* ~ *They got him a new car*.

Since *be* and *have* constitute almost all the non-modal auxiliary verbs in English, that makes *get* very useful in all kinds of idioms that use those auxiliaries. This is where the famous equation of *have got* and *have* comes from, as well as the American use of *gotten* as an alternate past participle of *get*.

> When I was learning Spanish in Mexico back in 1979-80, I was devastated to discover that, while it is otherwise an exemplary inflected language and a pleasure to speak, Spanish has no general inchoative verb, idiom, or other construction the likes of English *get*, which you can always mine for **some** way to indicate change of state.

Comment: Where do you get the notion that ‘inchoative’ means any aspect of change of state, comprising both beginning and end? Inchoation is specifically the _beginning_ of a state or action, not its end. At a broader level, of course, every stage of everything is simultaneously beginning, middle and end of a state, but that’s completely irrelevant to what inchoative constructions are, since they are about which aspect of a state you _focus_ on; otherwise the term would be meaningless. (Also, _become_ isn’t a contraction of _come to be_ in any sense of the word.)

Comment: Obviously you use the term differently.  Given the lack of sophistication in the question, I didn't think going into details any more than I did would be useful. And it's closed anyway.

Comment: Thank you for your illustration! Very understandable for beginners like me.

Comment: "Obviously you use the term differently." This seems like a bit of a cop-out. If I use a term of art in linguistics in a way divergent to the community, I should not expect others to understand. _All_ senses of "inchoative" in the literature that I'm aware of relate to the incipient phase of an action, and not simply a "change of state". Are you aware of any work that uses the term in the way you do?

Comment: It is generally the beginning that is noted, but the beginning of any state or action is the end of something else; there are terms for inceptive and terminative states and events. I consider them varieties of inchoation. When you get to causation, the plot thickens.